# Can I make a variable of a class into a function with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class

Is it possible to make a variable "a" into a new class "simple".
Then make a into a function so I can call a like 'a("hey")'? And if so how? Thanks!

```
class simple {
    /*
    function(c) {
        console.log(c);
    }
    */
}

let a = new simple();
let b = a('hey');
```

Comment: Sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain what you're trying to solve with this?

Comment: Agreed with VLAZ here, seems like either creating a function that you can call, or a method on a class would be the right solution. Why does your class instance need to be a callable function itself?

Comment: I don't really have a thing I'm trying to solve with this, I'm just trying to understand JavaScript in every way, and this came to my mind so I was just wondering.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to do it